# Simple Ruby on Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can somebody give link to RoR's "hello world" ? Where writen **how RoR works** with simple example?
thanks.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/groups/470731169693989/?fref=ts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Michael Hartl (co-author of [RailsSpace](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321480791)) is working on a very nice free-online Rails tutorial: [Learn Rails by Example](http://www.railstutorial.org/book).

He's only completed the first 4 chapters, but chapter 1 takes you through deploying a Rails app using Heroku, so it's pretty useful already.

I also turn to the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) as the best source of official documentation.

Comment: Note: The book is now done (and has been since July of 2010).

Answer (score 2):

Some of the best resources for Ruby and Rails are :

For rails reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/
For API Reference: http://www.gotapi.com/rubyrails
Actual Rails Site: http://rubyonrails.org/

If you want to refer some books; I find The Rails way by Obie fernandez really good.
To get a gist of Rails, you can use Head First Series.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit more complicated than "hello world", but the [screencast](http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts) on how to create a weblog in 15 minutes on the ruby on rails website is a rather good introduction.